# How to get event.target.id on fa-icon (angular)?

Tags: angular, event-handling, icons, mouseevent

Somehow fa-icon 'swallows' event.target.id.
I have the following in my component.html:

```
 <div id="STATUS_OK" class="unit dropdown-item" (click)="filterStatus($event)" [ngClass]="{ 'unit-selected' : STATUS_OK == true }">
     <input id="STATUS_OK" type="checkbox" name="unit" [(ngModel)]="STATUS_OK">          
     <fa-icon   id="STATUS_OK"  icon="check-circle" [ngStyle]="{'color':'#417505'}"></fa-icon>
     OK
</div>
```

I want to get event.target.id in my comopnent.ts file:

```
filterStatus(ev) {

      console.log(ev.target.id) // works for div and input, but doesn't work for fa-icon

  }
```

So my question is how to get event.target.id if I click on the icon.(Everything works perfectly if I click inside the div but outside the icon)

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz eaxmple?

Comment: hi you can check the favicon in the event path: Array(7) you can find here all your child element under the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `id` is not present is probably that `fa-icon` has an child HTML node that is the actual `target` of the `click` event.

Also note, that only one element on page is allowed to have unique `id` value.

Correct solution would be to pass the `STATUS_OK` as the event callback parameter.

`(click)="filterStatus($event, 'STATUS_OK')"`

```
<div class="unit dropdown-item" (click)="filterStatus($event, 'STATUS_OK')" [ngClass]="{ 'unit-selected' : STATUS_OK == true }">
     <input type="checkbox" name="unit" [(ngModel)]="STATUS_OK">          
     <fa-icon icon="check-circle" [ngStyle]="{'color':'#417505'}"></fa-icon>
     OK
</div>

filterStatus(ev, status) {
    console.log(status)    
}
```